# Can't assign value to undefined variable

Tags: javascript, node.js

I get parameters from a request. Sometimes "number" is set, sometimes it's not. When it's not, i want to set it to 1 but it doesn't work

```
        var nombre = parameter.number;
        console.log("Nombre : " + nombre);
        console.log("Nombre : " + JSON.stringify(nombre));
        if(nombre==undefined || nombre ==null || JSON.stringify(nombre)=="")
            nombre=1;
        console.log(nombre);
```

Here's what i get in console :

- 2018-08-06T09:42:42.884852+00:00 app[web.1]: Nombre :
- 2018-08-06T09:42:42.884941+00:00 app[web.1]: Nombre : ""
- 2018-08-06T09:42:42.885026+00:00 app[web.1]:undefined

Comment: whats the type of nombre ? have you tried if(nombre === undefined ?

Comment: @Stakvino Did you read the question? :P 3rd line from the bottom.

Comment: your code just works fine when I tested it

Answer (score 2):

Simply use `if(!nombre)` as a condition. It works for those which you are trying to compare:

```js
//for undefined
var nombre = undefined;
if(!nombre)
    nombre=1;
console.log(nombre);
//for null
nombre = null;
if(!nombre)
    nombre=1;
console.log(nombre);
//for ''
nombre = '';
if(!nombre)
    nombre=1;
console.log(nombre);
```

Answer (score 2):

The logical or operators (`||`) in JS will return the value of its left side if truthy<sup>[1]</sup> otherwise the value of the right side.

So

```
 var nombre = parameter.number || 1;
```

will give `nombre` the value 1 any time `parameter.number` isn't treated as true.

If you need to check for `undefined` specifically then you need to check for `undefined` explicitly (but in practice it is rare you want to treat `null` differently).

```
 var nombre = parameter.number !== undefined ? parameter.number : 1;
```

---

<sup>[1]</sup> "Truthy": values that JS treat as true when it needs a boolean value. Eg. `"0"`, a non-empty string, is treated as true.

Comment: @JonasW. Yes. Hence the explicit option (given empty string and null are included I extrapolated with the base case).

Answer (score 0):

```
  JSON.stringify(nombre) == ""
```

That comparison won't work. As you see in the console, `nombre` is actually stringified to '""' (a string that contains two "), so your comparison will fail as the string is not empty (""). So you actually want to do:

```
 nombre === ""
```